# Can my employer change the terms of my compensation in my employement contract, and do I have to agree with it?

Tags: salary, canada, bonus, employment-agreement

Location: Ontario, Canada.

I'm current a full time employee at a small company in Ontario, Canada. My employment contract states that my yearly salary is X, and that I'm entitled to a bonus every year, up to Y% of my salary. The bonus scheme is very generous, and was put in place by the board of the company in order to attract and retain talent. The terms of my salary and the bonus scheme are detailed in my original employment contract.

After this last fiscal year, the board has decided that the bonus scheme isn't working, there's still pretty high turnover and they are having trouble attracting talent. So they've decided to "renegotiate" the terms of our compensation in our employment contracts. Basically they are going to give everybody a raise (to align better with the market rates in the area), and scrap the bonus scheme.

I personally have never like the bonus scheme, and I have been a very vocal proponent of them getting rid of it and just paying everybody the market rate for their positions/experience. (NOTE: I have lots of experience and my current salary is already in line with the market rate in my area, but many other people at the company are definitely making way under the market rate).

That being said, even with a bump in my current salary, the loss of the bonus scheme is going to seriously impact my fiscal bottom-line going forward. As a high performer, my bonus was worth a very large percentage of my base salary. So even though I'm getting a raise, I will be making significantly less.

I did some research, and all the legalities around compensation in Ontario only really speak to reductions in pay, and no mention of bonuses that I can see.

If I don't sign the new agreement, will my previous contract stay in effect, and does the company have to honour it? Or are they giving me an ultimatum: sign the new contract, or you're terminated? Considering that many of the people working at the company are single-points of failure, this would reckless for the company as many of us might decide to just walk away at this point, which would basically destroy this company.

This all feels like it might fall under "Constructive Dismissal", sneakily pulling a "bait & switch" and making it feel like I'm getting a raise, but really they are cutting everybody's pay. Can they actually do this?

NOTE: There is no union here.

Comment: You should seek advice from an employment lawyer. Food for thought: https://www.rudnerlaw.ca/employer-change-benefits-package/ and https://www.entcounsel.com/tips-changing-employment-contracts-start-ups/

Comment: This is the reason you should NOT base your lifestyle on your yearly bonus. If the lack of your bonus, is going to seriously impact your fiscal bottom-line, then you should be asking for a yearly raise instead. I can't speak to the law in Canada, but I can't see a valid argument, against your company simply indicating nobody would receive a bonus in a given year if the new policy were to be challenged.  So while you will receive a raise, they could simply indicate, your bonus is 0%. **The bonus I have no doubt was NOT guaranteed.**

Answer (score 1):

You should check your contract to be sure, but it almost certainly says that bonuses are discretionary. Which means the company can choose to just not pay them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are ***in your contract***, or governed by law, employer policies are subject to change at any time.

You can try to persuade them that the change is a bad idea, either individually or collectively or by making a public nuisance of yourself. The latter two risk being invited to find a job elsewhere.

You can try to argue that if they make change X they owe the employees Y to balance it; I've succeeded at that once. (When the company went from pensions to 401k, I argued that if we were going to manage our own retirement funds the company needed to make serious investment and planning resources and services available; to their credit, they did so.)

But in the end, those are your available options short of leaving.